# What's the preferred way to create Domain Tables (look-up tables) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm reading Dan Chak's Enterprise Rails Book - Great Book.  In the book he discusses Domain Tables or Look-up Tables and suggests creating these table by adding insert statements to the schema definition - since the tables are unlikely to change.  The book was written prior to the advent of the seeds.rb file, so my question(s) is as follows:

1. Given the existence of the seeds file, is it preferable / better to use the seeds file to create Domain Tables or is it still preferable to use insert statements to the schema definition.
2. If inserts statements are still preferable, is it simply at matter of typing the insert statements and then running db:rake migrate.

Comment: Here's the concept we're referring to: http://enterpriserails.chak.org/full-text/chapter-7-domain-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question, and found this page looking to find how others resolved it.

I don't think its the best solution, but I ended up putting the domain data inside the model using find_or_create_by..., because I couldn't figure out how to get the seed data populated before the model instatiates during tests.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the domain data in the model using `find_or_create_by` caused some problems for me during tests. I believe the issue is that the data was inserted and the constant defined all during a test's db transaction. After the test example, the db transaction gets rolled back, leaving the still-instantiated constant pointing at a record that no longer exists.

So I put the domain data into `seeds.rb`. To prevent the issue that Docunext notes, of the model instantiating before the data is in the db, I use raw SQL for the inserts, as such:

```
   # in db/seeds.rb
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "INSERT INTO invoice_statuses(name) values ('Approved'), ('Sent'), ('Paid');"
```

And I configure the database_cleaner gem to skip all the domain tables when cleaning out the database in between tests:

```
    # in spec/support/database_cleaner.rb
    RSpec.configure do |config|

      domain_data = %w[aql_results invoice_statuses service_results remark_types]

      config.before(:suite) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion, { except: domain_data }
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
      end

      config.before(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
      end

      config.before(:each, :js => true) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion, { except: domain_data }
      end

      config.before(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.start
      end

      config.after(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
      end

    end
```